# Automark a directory as resource in IntelliJ 14?

Tags: intellij-idea

Is it possible to automark a directory as a resource ("Mark Directory As"->"Resource") in IntelliJ 14?

I have a structure with test and production projects which have Spring IOC files in src/main/conf. I would like to automark all conf directories as a resource.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to write a simple script that will edit your .iml files, which store this information. The .iml files use a simple XML format. You can mark directory as resource in one module, see the changes that were made, and apply the same changes to all other .iml files.